# How to make Cells overlap the section Footer in CollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a Newsstand app and for the shelves I'll use a fixed background image and some footers with another Image.

The problem is that when I add an image to my footer the cells seems to be flying.

I just want to **overlap the footer with the cells**.

I have this:

[image: flying pdfs]

And I want this:

[image: correct shelf]

I just don't have time to do a custom layout. Is there any way to do it in a simple way?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `sectionInset` property of the flow layout?

Comment: I don't see how it could help me to perform the overlap...can you show me a sample or a tutorial about how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this unanswered question while programming something similar. Although this is a very old question, it might help someone researching the same topic.

A negative sectionInset solves this problem:

```
let myFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
myFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -30, right: 0)

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = myFlowLayout
```